# Karate - While generating report on jenkins, it is also considering json file from Test data folder too. Why it is behaving differently there?

Tags: karate

As a result, cucumber report plugin can not generate proper report as it also contains json file from test data folder

My code for main runner class. also attached image for my folder structure.

class ExamplesTest {

```
// this will run all *.feature files that exist in sub-directories
// see https://github.com/intuit/karate#naming-conventions

@Karate.Test
Karate testAll() {
    return Karate.run().relativeTo(getClass());
}

@Test
void testruninParallel() {
   Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 1, "target/surefire-reports");
//        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:examples").tags("~@ignore").parallel(2);
        ExamplesTest.generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        if (results.getFailCount()!=0){
            System.out.println( results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}

private static void generateReport(String reportDir) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(reportDir), new String[]{"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.`enter code here`getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: totally depends on what's happening on jenkins, only you can figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your Jenkins is putting some extra JSON file in `target/surefire-reports` - you have to fix that. You can try modifying the logic in `generateReport` to ignore some files if needed.

Comment: In Jenkins we attach Cucumber-reports plugin. in that plugin we need to specify JSON  reports path. by default it's considering all JSON file in target folder I think. I specify target/surefire-reports in json reports path. Now it's working